Is it possible to defer a thread_local inititializaion?
If I've got a thread_local object defined in another thread-context in an outer function, is it possible to re-initialize the object in another thread ?
int main()
{
    thread_local string str( "hello world" );
    jthread( [&]
            {
                // re-init str for this thread if it hasn't been initialized yet
            } );
}


This might be a XY problem. Can you explain the actual use case ?

I just wanted to define a thread_local object not mutiple times for multiple threads.

Why not simply e.g. add a local variable inside the thread method ?

But maybe it is more useful it you try to explain WHAT you want to do instead of HOW you are trying to solve it now.

@PepijnKramer I want thread-local data and not shared data with one definition.

Yet you say "another thread-context" which is very confusing

@PepijnKramer The above example shows two thread-contexts.

Yes and it shows one thread_local variable that will only be from the main thread. (it can't be captured by the lambda). More here : Capturing a thread_local in a lambda

I really don't understand: str isn't visible on any other thread.

@G.M. It is visible on the mainthread, but only from main. (Which makes it an expensive local variable in a way)

@PepijnKramer Right, that's what I meant (although I worded it rather clumsily).  I think the OP needs to provide a more complete example showing the code they would like to be able to write -- even if it doesn't compile.

@G.M. No problem, even after 30 years C++ I still do that too (wording things clumsily). ;).

The main issue is that capturing static/global/thread_local variables in lambdas doesn't do anything.

You want to do Meyer's singleton but as thread_local instead of static so each thread has its own version and you don't need to repeat its definition in each function.
#include <string>
#include <thread>

std::string& GetThreadString()
{
    thread_local std::string str{"hello"};
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    // init an instance in first thread
    auto& str = GetThreadString(); 
    std::thread( []
            {
                // init another instance in second thread
                auto& str2 = GetThreadString();
            } ).join();
}

If you only need the one version that's inside the other thread you can use a lambda to defer initialization but you need to be very careful about your captures lifetimes.
#include <string>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    auto data = "hello";
    auto str_source = [=]()->auto&{
        thread_local std::string str{data};
        return str;
        };
    std::thread( [&]
            {
                // object initialized here only once
                auto& str = str_source();
                // already initialized, just return it
                auto& str2 = str_source();
            } ).join();
}

